# Accessing salesforce metadata using python simple-salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

When reading the [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/heroku/simple-salesforce) docs, it only shows accessing object metadata using hard-coded methods like such:

```
sf.Contact.metadata()
```

Is there no way to do something like this?

```
sf["Contact"].metadata()
```

I want to loop through a list of objects and retrieve all these objects fields, but it seems like this isn't possible due to the limitation seen above.

```
for obj in objects:
    fields = [x["name"] for x in sf[obj].describe()["fields"]]
    # processing for each object
```

Is there any way to access object metadata using a string parameter, instead of a hard-coded value?

Answer (score 5):

The sf. interface is actually call to the the **get_attr** method in the Salesforce class.

**get_attr** returns the value of SFType(name, self.session_id, self.sf_instance, self.sf_version, self.proxies).

You could do what you would like with the following:

```
from simple_salesforce import SFType
....
sf_object = ['Case', 'Contact', 'Account', 'Custom1__c', 'Custom2__c']
for each in sf_object:
    SFType(each, sf.session_id, sf.sf_instance, sf.sf_version, sf.proxies).metadata()
```

Hope that helps.